# Why do passing 'positive' and 'negative' parameters into gensim's most_similar function not return the same as the vector math results?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

```
model.similar_by_vector(model['king'] - model['man'] + model['woman'], topn=1)[0]
```

Results in

```
('king', 0.8551837205886841)
```

Whereas

```
model.most_similar(positive=['king', 'queen'], negative=['man'], topn=1)[0]
```

Gives a different answer (the one you'd expect)

`('monarch', 0.6350384950637817)`

But I'd expect both of these to return the same thing. Am I misunderstanding how vector math should be performed on these vectors?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the source code for the `most_similar()` (and `similar_by_vector()`) methods if you'd like to closely review how what they're doing is different than what you might expect, for example by browsing the project's source repository online:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f97d0e793faa57877a2bbedc15c287835463eaa9/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L491

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f97d0e793faa57877a2bbedc15c287835463eaa9/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L598

In particular, there are likely a couple factors at play in the discrepancy you're seeing:

- When you supply look-up keys (word-tokens) to `most_similar()`, it will disqualify returning those same keys as answers, on the assumption you want the answer that's not already in your passed-in-parameters. That is, even if the target-location is closest to `'king'`, if `'king'` was one of the supplied keys, it will be ignored as a possible ranked response.
- `most_similar()` uses the unit-length normalized versions of each input word (via the use of `word_vec(word, use_norm=True)` for lookup, whereas a bracket-lookup (like `model[word]`) uses the raw, non-normalized vectors.